# How can I set an animated lockscreen? (MIUI 9)

Tags: android, themes, miui

I'm very happy with my new Mi Note 3 and I was searching for some good theme and I found the Star Track theme from Mi MIX 2, that it's amazing.

So my question was, if they can set an animated lockscreen could I set a video/gif/etc?

I already have a video divided in png files, the Theme Editor and have already check a little about the animation and editing the manifest.xml, but I hadn't found anything that really helps me to set my video divided on images on the lockscreen.

All help is appreciated, thanks so much.

Comment: have you tried this? http://en.miui.com/thread-128821-1-1.html

Comment: @Deepakkaku Yes, already tried and nothing helps me. I've already check the code on some themes, but all are different so I can't learn anything from there